# Migrating to Laravel 5, route:cache throwing exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Moving from Laravel 4.2 to 5.0

We have about ~200 routes in our API, most of them were Closures. So I've spent the better part of the last couple days converting them all to controller routes. Everything is back to being stable, but when I try to run `php artisan route:cache` it throws an exception

```
[Exception]
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

I did a ctrl+f for `function`, and the only ones left in the routes file are the two `Route::group` entries (which, yes, are closures...but surely only routes count...).

Any guidance? After the tediousness of the last two days, this error is...not what I wanted to see.

**EDIT**: Full stacktrace

Route cache cleared!

```
  [Exception]                                
  Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed  



Exception trace:
 () at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand.php:95
 serialize() at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand.php:95
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand->buildRouteCacheFile() at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand.php:65
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:523
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:115
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:101
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:94
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at C:\Users\cjtho_000\Desktop\ecapi_l5\artisan:36
```

**EDIT 2**: removed the route groups to test, still throws the exception

Comment: Could you drop a `-v` in there (`php artisan route:cache -v`) and include the stack trace in your question?

Comment: ...I did *not* know about that, added stacktrace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, the entirely unhelpful error message was trying to tell me that I had a **duplicate route** (copy paste error, I had two get routes matching the same uri).

Removing the duplicate fixed the issue.

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks.

Comment: i had the same issue. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Per your stack trace,

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand.php:95
serialize() at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand.php:95
```

Laravel is trying to serialize the routes collection [on line 95 of RouteCacheCommand.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0984411bda2cd2cc62a698f222b32ee991d57ff5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteCacheCommand.php#L95).

The error you're getting

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

looks like its PHP's standard "someone tried to serialize an anonymous function" exception message (vs. it might be a custom Laravel exception).

All this means **something** is adding an anonymous function (i.e. "closure") to your route collection.  If you're 100% sure you've removed them all from `routes.php`, my guess would be the route's in third party code somewhere.

It's best not to guess.  Try some debugging code that's something like the following

```
//un-tested pseudo debugging code

//get the application's routes, using the same 
//technique as the route:cache command
$app = require /path/to/your/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();
$routes = $app['router']->getRoutes();

//go through each route
foreach($routes as $route)
{
    //if the route is a closure
    if(is_object($route) && ($route instanceof Closure))
    {
        //use reflection to find out which file the closure is defined in
        $r = new ReflectionFunction($route);
        var_dump($route->getFileName ());
    }

}
```

This will let you figure out where the closure that's causing your problems is defined, which should be enough to point to the problem.

Comment: No luck. Every route shows as being a `Route`, no `Closure`s

Comment: @CJThompson Then I'd add some debugging to RouteCacheCommand.php itself  (or the same class in your compiled.php file) that `var_dump`s or otherwise logs the routes so you can see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Is L5 injecting routes somewhere, then? I don't have many modules loaded, but they're all critical...

Comment: @CJThompson No clue -- that's why I'd suggest adding some var_dumping of the route object to the RouteCacheCommand class to see what route PHP is choking on. Once you know that you can make a decision.